# Recyclerview item color change based on the text

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with some items, I want to change the background color of a few items to different color, how can I achieve this. 
Please see the image below. I want to change the background color or text color to different.
I have a recyclerview with some items, I want to change the background color of a few items to different color, how can I achieve this. 
Please see the image below. I want to change the background color or text color to different.

[image]

**MY_ADAPTER CLASS**

```
package com.cmrlabs.tracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class AdapterBusStops extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBusStops.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    AdapterBusStops(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_bus_stop, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        String bus = mData.get(position);
        holder.busStopName.setText(bus);
    }


    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView busStopName;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            busStopName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvBusStop);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share adapter code here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write logic like in onBindView for this TextView like

```
    String bus = mData.get(position);
    holder.busStopName.setText(bus);
    if (holder.busStopName.getText().toString().endsWith("BUS LEFT -") || holder.busStopName.getText().toString().contains("BUS LEFT")) {
        // Set text color what should be for Bus left
    } else {
        // Set text color what should be for upcoming buses
    }
```

Comment: I think in the condition it should be holder.busStopName.getText().toString()

Comment: @ChandraMouliPoreddy Did you tried updated answer? Share your code what you are trying

Comment: We should add getText().toString()     if ((holder.busStopName.getText().toString().endsWith("BUS LEFT") || holder.busStopName.getText().toString().contains("BUS LEFT"))) {
            // Set text color what should be for Bus left
            holder.busStopName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            holder.busStopName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            // Set text color what should be for upcoming buses
        }

Comment: First check should be 'holder.busStopName.getText().toString().endsWith("BUS LEFT -")'

Answer (score 3):

You can also store the color in your **model**

```
public class BusModel {
  private String text;
  private int color;


  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public int getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class AdapterBusStops extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBusStops.ViewHolder> {

    private List<BusModel> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    AdapterBusStops(Context context, List<BusModel> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_bus_stop, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        BusModel bus = mData.get(position);
        holder.busStopName.setText(bus.getText());
        holder.busStopName.setTextColor(bus.getColor());
    }


    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView busStopName;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            busStopName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvBusStop);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    BusModel getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```